# good practice in comment to @user

Tags: discussion, comments, users, top-users

After a lot of questions/answers/discussions on stackoveflow, I noticed that there are certain users that have a very good experience in some fields, and their answer are always clear and very useful.

Now, sometimes especially with difficult questions, I feel the need to explicitely attract their attention to the related post, considering their experience fundamental to have good advices on the posted question.

Do you consider a bad practice (maybe can disturb?) adding a comment to @desired_user down to your question, to attract his attention even if he's not currently involved in that discussion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the user hasn't participated in the question or answer you are commenting on, using @user won't notify him. So it won't work anyway.

I also wouldn't consider it good practice if it was possible, if you post a good and interesting question in a tag the user monitors, he'll answer it if he wants anyway. SO intentionally has no direct communication between users.

Comment: @Overbose: No. And that is a [by-design] "no". Every request to direct questions to users or provide private messaging has been shot down. And, quite properly in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd consider it bad practice if other users started "notifying" others about new questions they might be able to answer. People can set their own notifications on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) on tags they want to get notified about.

Imagine what would happen to "famous" 100K+ users who answer `c#` and `java` question, for example. There are several hundreds of new questions a day tagged with `c#` and `java` causing these poor guys/girls to get bombed to death with "notifications" from other users. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is content oriented, not user oriented. So if you ask your question with the right title and the apropriate tags, the chance that the knowledgable users visit it is optimized.

And if that doesn't get enough attention you can always add a bounty.

Some users have added contact information in their profiles, so if you really want to contact them you can.